# Is it possible to make the blend Xaml editor horizontal?

Tags: expression-blend, blend

I use blend a lot but sometimes I find its easier to make a slight tweak in xaml directly and would like to know if anyone has figured out how to make the editor sit horizontal to the designer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the Split View button active go to your top menu and choose **View -> Split View Orientation -> Split Views Horizontally**

Cheers!

Comment: Holy carp, I learned something about Blend!  Thanks for making my day Chris! :-)

Comment: Thanks a mill! I have been lamenting the amount of wasted space for weeks :)

Comment: No worries, glad you got a solution!